# Bug report: vote buttons don't work in low quality review queue

Tags: bug, review

While reviewing today, I noticed that I now have access to upvote/downvote buttons while reviewing (I don't remember having these before, but I could have just been unobservant). Unfortunately, they don't do anything in some review queues: the vote buttons do not actually cast any votes in the low quality queue.

Comment: Math is not listed as having received these changes yet. And if we were somehow granted access ahead of schedule, it would seem to me that these voting buttons should actually work, instead of not doing anything. (They *do* cast votes in the First Posts queue, which I think suggests something unintended could be going on here.)

Comment: Yes, @KReiser, hence I deleted my comments. But they may be preparing for activation as they roll things out.  I imagine there may be such glitches, but it's good you raised the question here.

Comment: Viola!  Check out the functionality of the review queues now.  I believe all the updates to review queues on our site were initiated and activated in the last hour or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review queue changes have been rolled out today and the buttons work now. Hooray!